# Why does pandas give NaN for column values when aggregating a column that doesn't exist?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's I want the sum of numbers by letter in the below DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  letter  number
0      A       1
1      A       2
2      B       3
3      B       4
4      C       5
5      C       6

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

This is really easy to accomplish:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('letter')[['number']].sum()
Out[11]:
        number
letter
A            3
B            7
C           11

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

But if I were to misspell my column, I'd get `NaN` values:

```
In [12]: df.groupby('letter')[['numberrrrr']].sum()
Out[12]:
        numberrrrr
letter
A              NaN
B              NaN
C              NaN

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

This led our team on quite a chase to determine where the bug was. Instead, we'd like an error statement, like:

```
In [13]: df.groupby('letter')['numberrrrr'].sum()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8ebcdeee8710> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby('letter')['numberrrrr'].sum()

/usr/local/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   2475         else:
   2476             if key not in self.obj:  # pragma: no cover
-> 2477                 raise KeyError(str(key))
   2478             # kind of a kludge
   2479             return SeriesGroupBy(self.obj[key], selection=key,

KeyError: 'numberrrrr'
```

Is there any particular reason that returning a DataFrame from an aggregation doesn't result in an error when the requested column in missing?

This is on pandas 0.13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in master/0.14.0 (releasing end of the week); rc1 is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases) if you'd like to try

```
In [7]: df.groupby('letter')[['number']].sum()
Out[7]: 
        number
letter        
A            3
B            7
C           11

In [8]: df.groupby('letter')[['numberrrr']].sum()
KeyError: "Columns not found: 'numberrrr'"

In [9]: pd.__version__
Out[9]: '0.14.0rc1-43-g0dec048'
```